# 12.04 LiveUSB turns to black screen on Test Installation

Tags: installation, nvidia, live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I wanted to try Ubuntu first before installing so I put it on a flash drive. I boot the the drive no problem but after I choose Try Ubuntu without installing the screen becomes a black screen with colorful lines in random places and stays there.

The flash drive works in my laptop (ATI Mobility Radeon 5650M) but I want this on my desktop. Is this fixable or am I outta luck?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) should help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following link:

[how to set nomodset for installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation)

you need to set nomodeset option in your grub file.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [Ankit's method](https://askubuntu.com/a/171928/22949) of setting `nomodeset`, is to instead set `nouveau.modeset=0`. Also I recommend using <kbd>Tab</kbd> instead of <kbd>e</kbd> in GRUB2 1.99-21ubuntu3.1 as <kbd>e</kbd> didn't do it for me.